# webpack: полноценный svg через тег object

Tags: svg, webpack

Всем привет,всем спасибо
я нубик в webpack неделю парюсь с ним .

ВОПРОС : как заставить webpack видеть js и css которые находятся в svg а сам он подключается через object .

в не сборке все прекрасно работает.
а в сборке не работает по причине простого отсутствия фаилов.

Cам svg  он видит и добавляет в сборку ,а вот то что внутри нет.
Поиск на эту тему без остановки не дал не каких результатов .Такое чувство что только 'svg-inline-loader' существует ,но как понял он не подходит.

Особо показать из кода мне нечего по причине полного не понимания что писать в конфиге относительно svg.
надеюсь я не один такой.